# Why are images getting a 404 error? My image path seems to be correct and works locally

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, http-status-code-404

I can't seem to figure out why my images are throwing a 404 error after I sync to github? My file paths work locally... Please help!

[Front End](https://danielle93.github.io/piercingsbyniles/) | 
[Back End](https://github.com/danielle93/piercingsbyniles)

All images are within a figure element an the figure element is within a main element

```
<main class="gallery">

    <figure>
      <a class="thumb" data-sub-html="#cap-one" href="img/portfolio/fullsize/septum_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/septum_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a data-sub-html="#cap-two" href="img/portfolio/fullsize/tongue_web_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/tongue_web_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a data-sub-html="#cap-two" href="img/portfolio/fullsize/AntiTragus_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/AntiTragus_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>


      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/conch_double_1">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/conch_double_1" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/conch_double_paired_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/conch_double_paired_1" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/conch_0g+tragus.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/conch_0g+tragus.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/dahlia_paired_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/dahlia_paired_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/daith_tragus_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/daith_tragus_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/eyebrow_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/eyebrow_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/tragus_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/tragus_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

        <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/tragus_double.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/tragus_double.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/Flat_Triple_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/Flat_Triple_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/helix_double_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/helix_double_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/helix_double_secondlobe.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/helix_double_secondlobe.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/helix_double_conch_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/helix_double_conch_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/helix_triple_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/helix_triple_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/helix_triple_forward_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/helix_triple_forward_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/industrial_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/industrial_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/industrial_2.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/industrial_2.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/industrial_3.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/industrial_3.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/industrial_double_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/industrial_double_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/labret_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/labret_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/labret_double_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/labret_double_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/labret_vertical+septum.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/labret_vertical+septum.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/labret_vertical_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/labret_vertical_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/labret_vertical_2.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/labret_vertical_.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/lobe_initial2g.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/lobe_initial2g.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/lobes_paired_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/lobes_paired_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/lobes_paired_2.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/lobes_paired_2.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/lowbret_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/lowbret_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/lowbret_2.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/lowbret_2.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/monroe.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/monroe.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/navel_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/navel_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/navel_2.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/navel_2.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/nipple_paired_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/nipple_paired_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/nipple_paired_2.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/nipple_paired_2.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/nostril+monroe.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/nostril+monroe.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/nostril+philtrum.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/nostril+philtrum.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/nostril_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/nostril_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/nostril_2.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/nostril_2.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/nostril_3.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/nostril_3.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/nostril_double+septum_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/nostril_double+septum_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/nostril_double_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/nostril_double_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/nostrils_paired_0gseptum.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/nostrils_paired_0gseptum.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/pairedlabrets_pairedverticallabrets_manroe.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/pairedlabrets_pairedverticallabrets_manroe.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/philtrum_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/philtrum_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/philtrume_septum_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/philtrume_septum_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/rook.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/rook.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/rook_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/rook_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/rook_double_1.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/rook_double_1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/surfaceanchor.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/surfaceanchor.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/surfaceanchor_paired.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/surfaceanchor_paired.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

      <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/surfaceanchor_unicornmagic.jpg">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/surfaceanchor_unicornmagic.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
```

Comment: "my file paths work locally" ... but what do they look like?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [**help article**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions, and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Answer (score 0):

Your page is trying to look for images in the following folder:

https://danielle93.github.io/piercingsbyniles/img/portfolio/thumbnail/

When your images are **actually** in:

https://danielle93.github.io/piercingsbyniles/img/thumbnail/

Simply update the links to point to the correct folder :)

You're currently referencing files such as:

`<img src="img/portfolio/thumbnail/septum_1.jpg" alt="">`,

but **should** be referencing the files like:

`<img src="img/thumbnail/septum_1.jpg" alt="">`.

Note the filepath lacks the `portfolio` folder.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Oh!! Thank you! I forgot to add my portfolio folder to my git site!

Comment: That would explain it :) Assuming you add the folder correctly, you shouldn't have to modify the links, though if you were to modify the links, this would be how you would do it :)

Comment: Glad to hear this answer solved the problem for you. Please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)